# Managing two roles in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two roles, the admin and the teacher. The admin and teacher accounts can login however when I logged in the teacher account it will redirect to admin page. I don't know if my code is right as well. I'm a newbie at using codeigniter so please bear with me.

So here's my controller:

```
public function login_validation(){

  $this->load->library('form_validation');


  $this->form_validation->set_rules('idnum', 'ID Number', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentials');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');

  if ($this->form_validation->run()){
     //$this->load->model('model_users');
     $this->load->model('model_role');
     $data = array(
           'login_id' => $this->input->post('idnum'),
           'is_logged_in' => 1,
             'role' => $this->model_role->scalar('user_account','role')

        );

     $this->session->set_userdata($data);
     redirect('site/members'); 
  } else {
     $data['title'] = "Outcome-based Education";

     $this->load->view("index/header", $data);
     $this->load->view("index/view_home");
     $this->load->view("index/footer");
  }
}

public function members(){

  if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') && $this->session->userdata('role', 'admin')){
     $this->load->view('login/admin');
  }  elseif($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') && $this->session->userdata('role', 'teacher')){
     $this->load->view('login/members');
  } 

     else{  
     redirect('site/restricted');
  }
}
```

And this is my model:

```
public function can_log_in(){

        $this->db->where('login_id', $this->input->post('idnum'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));

        $query = $this->db->get('user_account');

        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, what's your question? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your members function you are not actually checking the value of the role session data, you are just checking that it exists. You need to change :

```
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') && $this->session->userdata('role', 'admin')){
```

to:

```
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') && $this->session->userdata('role') == 'admin'){
```

As you will see, there is only 1 parameter that can be passed into the $this->session->userdata() function:

```
/**
 * Fetch a specific item from the session array
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function userdata($item)
{
    return ( ! isset($this->userdata[$item])) ? FALSE : $this->userdata[$item];
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. The one you answered actually worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

when you perform login action , From where you are calling can_log_in() method of model , Even you load the model but you are calling only $this->model_role->scalar('user_account','role') method which you give only "admin" parameter results in response .