# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in model_role.php on line 10

Tags: php, syntax-error

i tried to debug it but i really don't know what's causing the error. i already traced the missing brackets but i think there's none. so please help!

```
<?php

class Model_role extends CI_Model {

    public function scalar($user_account, $role){

            $this->db->where('login_id', $this->input->post('idnum'));
            $this->db->select($role);                                                                                                                     z

            $query = $this->db->get($user_account);
            $row = $query->row_array();
            return $row['role'];
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: What changed [**since yesterday?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27096002/)

Comment: nothing. i checked my back up of this file and it's just the same.

Comment: `($role);                                                                                                                     z` stray letter z there, tucked over way to the right. If it's in your working code, remove it.

Comment: `($role); 118 spaces then => z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a stray `z` way to the right of `$this->db->select($role);` Can you search for `z` in your editor and see if it comes up?